# Condense If-Else conditions in for loops

Tags: java, loops, if-statement

So i have the following code and I am trying to condense the if else sea I have created . I don't know If it possible to help me with that though :p. If there is any more information I have to provide you please ask.

```
public class Pvp extends JPanel implements ActionListener {
    JButton[] gridButtons;
    int count = 0;
    int sign = 0;
    char[] grid;
    char winner;

    public Pvp() {

        setBackground(new Color(255, 0, 51));
        setBorder(new LineBorder(new Color(0, 0, 0), 2, true));
        setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0));

        JLabel lblPvpGamemode = new JLabel("PvP Gamemode");
        lblPvpGamemode.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
        lblPvpGamemode.setFont(new Font("Timber", Font.PLAIN, 50));
        add(lblPvpGamemode, BorderLayout.NORTH);

        JPanel gamePanel = new JPanel();
        gamePanel.setBackground(new Color(255, 102, 51));
        add(gamePanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        gamePanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(3, 3, 0, 0));
        gamePanel.setBorder(new LineBorder(new Color(0, 0, 0), 1, true));

        gridButtons = new JButton[9];
        grid = new char[9];

        for (int cntr = 0; cntr < 9; cntr++) {
            gridButtons[cntr] = new JButton();
            gamePanel.add(gridButtons[cntr]);
            gridButtons[cntr].setEnabled(true);
            gridButtons[cntr].addActionListener(this);
            gridButtons[cntr].setBackground(Color.BLACK);
            grid[cntr] = ' ';

        }

    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        count++;
        for (int cntr = 0; cntr <= 8; cntr++) {
            if (gridButtons[cntr] == e.getSource()) {
                if (sign % 2 == 0) {
                    gridButtons[cntr]
                            .setFont(new Font("Timber", Font.PLAIN, 80));
                    gridButtons[cntr].setText("X");
                    gridButtons[cntr].setEnabled(false);
                    gridButtons[cntr].setForeground(new Color(255, 102, 51));
                    grid[cntr] = 'X';
                } else {
                    gridButtons[cntr]
                            .setFont(new Font("Timber", Font.PLAIN, 80));
                    gridButtons[cntr].setText("O");
                    gridButtons[cntr].setEnabled(false);
                    gridButtons[cntr].setForeground(Color.BLACK);
                    grid[cntr] = 'O';

                }
                if (grid[0] == 'X' && grid[0] == grid[1] && grid[1] == grid[2]) {
                    int yes;
                    yes = JOptionPane
                            .showOptionDialog(
                                    null,
                                    "The game is over! Xs have won! Do you want to play again?",
                                    "Game over", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION,
                                    JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION, null, null, null);
                    if (yes == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) {

                        for (int cntr2 = 0; cntr2 < 9; cntr2++) {
                            gridButtons[cntr2].setText("");
                            gridButtons[cntr2].setEnabled(true);
                            grid[cntr2] = ' ';

                        }
                        count = 0;
                        sign = 0;
                        FormPanel formPanel = new FormPanel();
                        formPanel.firePvp();
                        return;
                    }

                } else if (grid[0] == 'O' && grid[0] == grid[1]
                        && grid[1] == grid[2]) {
                    int yes;
                    yes = JOptionPane
                            .showOptionDialog(
                                    null,
                                    "The game is over! Os have won! Do you want to play again?",
                                    "Game over", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION,
                                    JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION, null, null, null);
                    if (yes == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) {

                        for (int cntr2 = 0; cntr2 < 9; cntr2++) {
                            gridButtons[cntr2].setText("");
                            gridButtons[cntr2].setEnabled(true);
                            grid[cntr2] = ' ';

                        }
                        count = 0;
                        sign = 0;
                        FormPanel formPanel = new FormPanel();
                        formPanel.firePvp();
                        return;
                    }

                } else if (grid[0] == 'X' && grid[0] == grid[3]
                        && grid[3] == grid[6]) {
                    winner = 'X';
                    int yes;
                    yes = JOptionPane
                            .showOptionDialog(
                                    null,
                                    "The game is over! Os have won! Do you want to play again?",
                                    "Game over", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION,
                                    JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION, null, null, null);
                    if (yes == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) {

                        for (int cntr2 = 0; cntr2 < 9; cntr2++) {
                            gridButtons[cntr2].setText("");
                            gridButtons[cntr2].setEnabled(true);
                            grid[cntr2] = ' ';

                        }
                        count = 0;
                        sign = 0;
                        FormPanel formPanel = new FormPanel();
                        formPanel.firePvp();
                        return;
                    }

                }

                else if (grid[0] == 'O' && grid[0] == grid[3]
                        && grid[3] == grid[6]) {
                    winner = 'O';
                    int yes;
                    yes = JOptionPane
                            .showOptionDialog(
                                    null,
                                    "The game is over! Os have won! Do you want to play again?",
                                    "Game over", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION,
                                    JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION, null, null, null);
                    if (yes == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) {

                        for (int cntr2 = 0; cntr2 < 9; cntr2++) {
                            gridButtons[cntr2].setText("");
                            gridButtons[cntr2].setEnabled(true);
                            grid[cntr2] = ' ';

                        }
                        count = 0;
                        sign = 0;
                        FormPanel formPanel = new FormPanel();
                        formPanel.firePvp();
                        return;
                    }

                }

                else if (grid[6] == 'X' && grid[6] == grid[7]
                        && grid[7] == grid[8]) {
                    winner = 'X';
                    int yes;
                    yes = JOptionPane
                            .showOptionDialog(
                                    null,
                                    "The game is over! Xs have won! Do you want to play again?",
                                    "Game over", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION,
                                    JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION, null, null, null);
                    if (yes == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) {

                        for (int cntr2 = 0; cntr2 < 9; cntr2++) {
                            gridButtons[cntr2].setText("");
                            gridButtons[cntr2].setEnabled(true);
                            grid[cntr2] = ' ';

                        }
                        count = 0;
                        sign = 0;
                        FormPanel formPanel = new FormPanel();
                        formPanel.firePvp();
                        return;
                    }

                } else if (grid[6] == 'O' && grid[6] == grid[7]
                        && grid[7] == grid[8]) {
                    winner = 'O';
                    int yes;
                    yes = JOptionPane
                            .showOptionDialog(
                                    null,
                                    "The game is over! Os have won! Do you want to play again?",
                                    "Game over", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION,
                                    JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION, null, null, null);
                    if (yes == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) {

                        for (int cntr2 = 0; cntr2 < 9; cntr2++) {
                            gridButtons[cntr2].setText("");
                            gridButtons[cntr2].setEnabled(true);
                            grid[cntr2] = ' ';

                        }
                        count = 0;
                        sign = 0;
                        FormPanel formPanel = new FormPanel();
                        formPanel.firePvp();
                        return;
                    }

                } else if (grid[2] == 'X' && grid[2] == grid[5]
                        && grid[5] == grid[8]) {
                    winner = 'X';
                    int yes;
                    yes = JOptionPane
                            .showOptionDialog(
                                    null,
                                    "The game is over! Xs have won! Do you want to play again?",
                                    "Game over", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION,
                                    JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION, null, null, null);
                    if (yes == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) {

                        for (int cntr2 = 0; cntr2 < 9; cntr2++) {
                            gridButtons[cntr2].setText("");
                            gridButtons[cntr2].setEnabled(true);
                            grid[cntr2] = ' ';

                        }
                        count = 0;
                        sign = 0;
                        FormPanel formPanel = new FormPanel();
                        formPanel.firePvp();
                        return;
                    }

                } else if (grid[2] == 'O' && grid[2] == grid[5]
                        && grid[5] == grid[8]) {
                    winner = 'O';
                    int yes;
                    yes = JOptionPane
                            .showOptionDialog(
                                    null,
                                    "The game is over! Os have won! Do you want to play again?",
                                    "Game over", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION,
                                    JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION, null, null, null);
                    if (yes == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) {

                        for (int cntr2 = 0; cntr2 < 9; cntr2++) {
                            gridButtons[cntr2].setText("");
                            gridButtons[cntr2].setEnabled(true);
                            grid[cntr2] = ' ';

                        }
                        count = 0;
                        sign = 0;
                        FormPanel formPanel = new FormPanel();
                        formPanel.firePvp();
                        return;
                    }

                } else if (grid[3] == 'X' && grid[3] == grid[4]
                        && grid[4] == grid[5]) {
                    winner = 'X';
                    int yes;
                    yes = JOptionPane
                            .showOptionDialog(
                                    null,
                                    "The game is over! Xs have won! Do you want to play again?",
                                    "Game over", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION,
                                    JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION, null, null, null);
                    if (yes == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) {

                        for (int cntr2 = 0; cntr2 < 9; cntr2++) {
                            gridButtons[cntr2].setText("");
                            gridButtons[cntr2].setEnabled(true);
                            grid[cntr2] = ' ';

                        }
                        count = 0;
                        sign = 0;
                        FormPanel formPanel = new FormPanel();
                        formPanel.firePvp();
                        return;
                    }

                } else if (grid[3] == 'O' && grid[3] == grid[4]
                        && grid[4] == grid[5]) {
                    winner = 'O';
                    int yes;
                    yes = JOptionPane
                            .showOptionDialog(
                                    null,
                                    "The game is over! Os have won! Do you want to play again?",
                                    "Game over", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION,
                                    JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION, null, null, null);
                    if (yes == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) {

                        for (int cntr2 = 0; cntr2 < 9; cntr2++) {
                            gridButtons[cntr2].setText("");
                            gridButtons[cntr2].setEnabled(true);
                            grid[cntr2] = ' ';

                        }
                        count = 0;
                        sign = 0;
                        FormPanel formPanel = new FormPanel();
                        formPanel.firePvp();
                        return;
                    }

                } else if (grid[0] == 'X' && grid[0] == grid[4]
                        && grid[4] == grid[8]) {
                    winner = 'X';
                    int yes;
                    yes = JOptionPane
                            .showOptionDialog(
                                    null,
                                    "The game is over! Xs have won! Do you want to play again?",
                                    "Game over", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION,
                                    JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION, null, null, null);
                    if (yes == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) {

                        for (int cntr2 = 0; cntr2 < 9; cntr2++) {
                            gridButtons[cntr2].setText("");
                            gridButtons[cntr2].setEnabled(true);
                            grid[cntr2] = ' ';

                        }
                        count = 0;
                        sign = 0;
                        FormPanel formPanel = new FormPanel();
                        formPanel.firePvp();
                        return;
                    }

                } else if (grid[2] == 'O' && grid[0] == grid[4]
                        && grid[4] == grid[8]) {
                    winner = 'O';
                    int yes;
                    yes = JOptionPane
                            .showOptionDialog(
                                    null,
                                    "The game is over! Os have won! Do you want to play again?",
                                    "Game over", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION,
                                    JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION, null, null, null);
                    if (yes == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) {

                        for (int cntr2 = 0; cntr2 < 9; cntr2++) {
                            gridButtons[cntr2].setText("");
                            gridButtons[cntr2].setEnabled(true);
                            grid[cntr2] = ' ';

                        }
                        count = 0;
                        sign = 0;
                        FormPanel formPanel = new FormPanel();
                        formPanel.firePvp();
                        return;
                    }

                } else if (grid[2] == 'X' && grid[2] == grid[4]
                        && grid[4] == grid[6]) {
                    winner = 'X';
                    int yes;
                    yes = JOptionPane
                            .showOptionDialog(
                                    null,
                                    "The game is over! Xs have won! Do you want to play again?",
                                    "Game over", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION,
                                    JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION, null, null, null);
                    if (yes == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) {

                        for (int cntr2 = 0; cntr2 < 9; cntr2++) {
                            gridButtons[cntr2].setText("");
                            gridButtons[cntr2].setEnabled(true);
                            grid[cntr2] = ' ';

                        }
                        count = 0;
                        sign = 0;
                        FormPanel formPanel = new FormPanel();
                        formPanel.firePvp();
                        return;
                    }

                } else if (grid[6] == 'O' && grid[2] == grid[4]
                        && grid[4] == grid[6]) {
                    winner = 'O';
                    int yes;
                    yes = JOptionPane
                            .showOptionDialog(
                                    null,
                                    "The game is over! Os have won! Do you want to play again?",
                                    "Game over", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION,
                                    JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION, null, null, null);
                    if (yes == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) {

                        for (int cntr2 = 0; cntr2 < 9; cntr2++) {
                            gridButtons[cntr2].setText("");
                            gridButtons[cntr2].setEnabled(true);
                            grid[cntr2] = ' ';

                        }
                        count = 0;
                        sign = 0;
                        FormPanel formPanel = new FormPanel();
                        formPanel.firePvp();
                        return;
                    }

                }else if (grid[1] == 'X' && grid[1] == grid[4]
                        && grid[4] == grid[7]) {
                    winner = 'X';
                    int yes;
                    yes = JOptionPane
                            .showOptionDialog(
                                    null,
                                    "The game is over! Xs have won! Do you want to play again?",
                                    "Game over", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION,
                                    JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION, null, null, null);
                    if (yes == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) {

                        for (int cntr2 = 0; cntr2 < 9; cntr2++) {
                            gridButtons[cntr2].setText("");
                            gridButtons[cntr2].setEnabled(true);
                            grid[cntr2] = ' ';

                        }
                        count = 0;
                        sign = 0;
                        FormPanel formPanel = new FormPanel();
                        formPanel.firePvp();
                        return;
                    }

                } else if (grid[1] == 'O' && grid[1] == grid[4]
                        && grid[4] == grid[7]) {
                    winner = 'O';
                    int yes;
                    yes = JOptionPane
                            .showOptionDialog(
                                    null,
                                    "The game is over! Os have won! Do you want to play again?",
                                    "Game over", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION,
                                    JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION, null, null, null);
                    if (yes == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) {

                        for (int cntr2 = 0; cntr2 < 9; cntr2++) {
                            gridButtons[cntr2].setText("");
                            gridButtons[cntr2].setEnabled(true);
                            grid[cntr2] = ' ';

                        }
                        count = 0;
                        sign = 0;
                        FormPanel formPanel = new FormPanel();
                        formPanel.firePvp();
                        return;
                    }

                }

            }

        }
        if (count >= 9) {
            int yes;
            yes = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null,
                    "The game is over! Do you want to play again?",
                    "Game over", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION,
                    JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION, null, null, null);

            if (yes == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) {

                for (int cntr2 = 0; cntr2 < 9; cntr2++) {
                    gridButtons[cntr2].setText(" ");
                    gridButtons[cntr2].setEnabled(true);
                    grid[cntr2] = ' ';

                }
                count = 0;
                sign = 0;
                FormPanel formPanel = new FormPanel();
                formPanel.firePvp();
                return;
            }

        }

        sign++;

    }
```

Comment: Start by [refactoring](http://refactoring.com/) your code into methods.  What you currently have is virtually unreadable.

Comment: This is crazy! Is it the Arabian sea of the if else statements?

Comment: The `tic tac toe` game?

Comment: @bayou.io yup , yes it is

Comment: @XOR IKR ? XD but it's more or less the same thing that's why I want to shorten it :p

Comment: Show us the code when you program the chess game :)

Comment: @bayou.io What chess game o.O

Answer (score 0):

I agree with azurefrog. Anywhere you have duplicate code, try to put that code into a function/method to call. Your code will be much shorter and readable. Example of code to put in method

```
if (yes == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) {

                    for (int cntr2 = 0; cntr2 < 9; cntr2++) {
                        gridButtons[cntr2].setText("");
                        gridButtons[cntr2].setEnabled(true);
                        grid[cntr2] = ' ';

                    }
                    count = 0;
                    sign = 0;
                    FormPanel formPanel = new FormPanel();
                    formPanel.firePvp();
                    return;
                }
```

Saw this exact code in 2 or more places.